# vim split files in new tab

Tags: split

I'm looking for something like

```
:tabsplit file1 file2
```

which will open the two files in a new tab that is split with file1 in one split and file2 in another split

I really want something like `tabvsplit`. Currently, I am using

```
:tabe file1
:vsp file2
```

not too bad, but could be better, and I am wondering if there is something built-in that is easier to type and faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
:tabedit +sp\ file1 file2
```

You can create a new command for that, but that will make the quoting ugly. Something like this might work (warning, this is really ugly, but seems to work from my basic tests):

```
com! -nargs=+ -complete=file Tabsplit :let a=split(<q-args>) | if len(a) == 2 | exe ':tabedit +'. fnameescape('sp '. a[0]) fnameescape(a[1]) | else | echoerr "too many arguments" |endif
```

It basically checks, that the supplied arguments are exactly 2 and if that is the case, runs the `:tabedit +sp` command mentioned earlier and if not, will echo an error message.

I am not quite sure, the `fnameescape()` is needed for the file arguments. You need to test, if this is really required when using a filename that contains spaces.

Comment: *eyes widen* woah (to the second one). Thanks for the first tip. I'll check out second one after work.